# reg delete always bringing prompt in c#

Tags: c#

I'm using a commandline execute to run a reg delete /f. Now when I do it via commandline it works as intended, but if I run it from C# I still get a prompt.

Now I'm wondering where the erorr lies....thus why do I still get a prompt when I call the command via C# despite the /f parameter being used.

Edit: A small info here: .NET Framework is 3.5

The code that is being used is as follows:

```
LaunchProcessAndWait(@"cmd",
      @"/c reg delete " + "\"" 
      + @"HKLM\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main"+ "\"" 
      + @" /v DisableFirstRunCustomize /f",
        "");


public static string LaunchProcessAndWaitForOutput(string commandline, string args, bool returnError, bool returnOutput, string workingDir)
        {
            ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo(commandline, args);

            if (workingDir != null)
            {
                info.WorkingDirectory = workingDir;
            }

            info.UseShellExecute = false;
            info.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            info.RedirectStandardError = true;
            info.CreateNoWindow = true;

            Process p = Process.Start(info);

            string outStr = "";
            string errStr = "";

            p.OutputDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler((sender, e) =>
            {
                outStr += e.Data + "\r\n";
            });

            p.ErrorDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler((sender, e) =>
            {
                errStr += e.Data + "\r\n";
            });

            p.BeginOutputReadLine();
            p.BeginErrorReadLine();

            p.WaitForExit();

            p.Close();

            return "" + (returnOutput ? outStr : "") + (returnError ? errStr : "");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why are you calling out to the reg command when you can easily interact with the registry directly from C# code. And doing that, you won't write any prompt code at all so you definitely shouldn't see one.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever normally yes, but the machines I'm running the code on are....lets call it strange. First they can only run 3.5 framework and secondly.....half the time I try to do reg edits directly the internal security of the machines are raising a ruckus (no clue though why they like commandline reg edits but hate c# reg edits)

Comment: @Thomas, not sure it is the case, but have you tried running it as an Administrator?

Comment: @Yan yes I tried